# How to colorize text betwen " * " tags in message?

Tags: php

Anybody knows how i can achieve this:

I want post message and colorize everything between " * " Tags.
Like this:

```
This [*]is[*] test [*]message[*] :)
```

To:

```
This [yellow]is[/yellow]> test [yellow]message[/yellow] :)
```

I wroted something like this to achieve my goal:

```
if(preg_match_all('/\*(.*?)\*/',$message,$match)) {  
    $beforemessage = explode("*", $message, 2);      
    $message = $beforemessage[0]. " <font color='yellow'>" .$match[0][0].   "</font>";           
}
```

Howewer it returns only:

```
This [yellow]is[yellow]
```

Comment: `<font>` is deprecated and should never be used. See `<span>` and use CSS styles and HTML classnames.

Comment: why not just [yellow][/yellow]? Won't help much, but at least it'll be readable in this example.

Comment: I think you should really look at our code again. You'll notice that you never append the rest of your message.

Comment: You just have to hope that no one puts * in a message

Comment: Yep, you probably want to match [*], not just *. eg. use the regex `/\[\*\](.*?)\[\*\]/` instead of `/\*(.*?)\*/`. Otherwise it will mess up if there is a * anywhere in the text!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
$message = "This *is* test *message*";
echo preg_replace('/\*(.*?)\*/', '<font color="yellow">$1</font>', $message);

This <font color="yellow">is</font> test <font color="yellow">message</font>
```

preg_match_all returns an array of matches, but your code only ever replaces the FIRST match in that array. You'd have to loop over the array to handle the OTHER matches.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches when using regular expressions.

One is to do matching - keeping track of the position of the match and the length of the match. Then you can split up the original message into substrings and concatenate it all back together.

The other is to do search/replace using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, or similar approach:

```
<?php

$text = "Hello hello *bold* foo foo *fat* foo boo *think* end.";

$tagOpen = false;

function replaceAsterisk($matches) {
    global $tagOpen;

    $repl = "";

    if($tagOpen) {
        $repl = "</b>";
    } else {
        $repl = "<b>";
    }

    $tagOpen = !$tagOpen;

    return $repl;
}

$result =  preg_replace_callback( "/[*]/", "replaceAsterisk", $text);

echo $result;
```